# PHP Photo Gallery - after 12 images, make a second page?

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a really basic PHP photo gallery for my website, which gathers information from a MySQL database. Using a while loop, I list three images (from ID 1 to 3) in one row, and continue until 12 images have been displayed.

This works perfectly fine if you have uploaded 12 images, but some of my users have uploaded 12 and I need to know how to make another page for images 13-24, etc. I have looked at the source code of some PHP galleries yet nothing has helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your code setup, but mainly, you are talking about pagination.

A basic way to do that would be to add a URL param like http://www.exemple.com/photos?page=2,
detect that params in your PHP code, and fetch your photos in your Mysql database accordingly, something like that:

```
$num_per_page = 12;
$offset = $num_per_page * ($_GET['page'] - 1);
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos LIMIT $offset, $num_per_page";
```

Comment: This actually makes sense, I'll try it right now. Will report with results!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works with my gallery, so now I'll just have to add the page numbers. Once again, thank you!